# Laravel hasManyThrough issue with same named field of tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, orm, eloquent, has-many-through

These are the models I have :

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Category');
    }
    public function forms()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Form', 'Category');
    }
}

class Category extends \Eloquent {
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
    public function forms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Form');
    }
}

namespace App\Models;
class Form extends \Eloquent {
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }
}
```

Now I want to get one `Form` by its `id` so that its assured that the `Form` `belongsTo` a particular `User`.

So I am using :

```
$form   = $user->forms()->find($id);
```

It works fine but here comes with the issue that its showing `Category`.`name` instead of showing `Form`.`name`.  I know that its because both of the table has fields named `name`. I can change field name but its not a good solution.

How can I get rid of this issue in the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see where the error is.  The second parameter to the `find()` method is a list of columns to retrieve.  If you don't pass in this value, it defaults to "array(*)".  Because of this, when you do `$user->forms()->find($id);`, it is replacing the original `select forms.*, categories.user_id ...` with `select * ...`.  This also happens with the `first()` method.

This would happen with the `get()` method as well, but the HasManyThrough relationship overrides the `get()` method so that it adds in the proper select values when all that was chosen was "array(*)".

So, your solution should work fine. However, you don't need the `whereRaw`; `where` should work fine:

```
$forms = $user->forms()->where('forms.id', $id)->get();
```

Once you get the Collection, you are safe to use `first()` on the Collection, so you could do this, as well:

```
// first() on the Collection is fine; first() on the HasManyThrough relationship is not.
$form = $user->forms()->where('forms.id', $id)->get()->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the current solution:

```
$form   = $user->forms()->whereRaw('forms.id = ?', array($id))->get()->first();
```

This was the old wrong solution by using `->first()`:

```
$form   = $user->forms()->find($id)->first();
```

Comment: I think you had a different issue.  `find()` already does a `first()`.  Your proposed statement is equivalent to: `$user->forms()->where('id', '=', $id)->first()->first()`.

Comment: @patricus You are correct that the problem is in somewhere else. I will remove this answer. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Well, you'll have to do more to show that you actually have a problem.  The query generated by the hasManyThrough relationship doesn't select fields from the intermediate table, so it doesn't make any sense that it would show data from that table.  You can verify this by dumping the queries run with `var_dump(DB::getQueryLog());`.

Comment: @patricus The query generates fine: `select * from `forms` inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `forms`.`category_id` where `categories`.`user_id` = 1 and `forms`.`id` = 1 limit 1` and output also fine in phpmyadmin but wrong in Laravel. 
How ever I have made one workaround. Edited my answer.

Comment: The generated query is not correct.  The select statement generated by the relationship should be `forms.*, categories.user_id`, not `*`.  That helped figure out what the issue is, though.  I have posted an answer with details.